# Image uploaded to dropbox does not show after a while - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor, dropbox, carrierwave

I am using `ckeditor` and i upload images to dropbox which i configured using `carrierwave` and `minimagick` . After some days though the image does not appear on the blog post it says the following in console

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Not Authorized)`

example link (resource image)

`https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/5qo62va4g4uwsqn/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/1/content_1.png`

if i go to ckeditor and browse for image again and reload it, it works for a few days and then the same.

is there something that i am missing?

Comment: Can you share some code? What is the resource that fails to load exactly? If it's a Dropbox link, please post a sample.

Comment: @Greg i have posted the sample code that does not work . what else do you need? thanks

Comment: The sample link you added is the kind of link returned by the /media Dropbox Core API call: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media These links expire after four hours, so the behavior you describe is expected. If you need longer lived links, you may want to use /shares: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#shares but modify them for direct access: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

Comment: @Greg well it certainly does not expire after 4 hours so maybe its something else? Also i am using this gem `https://github.com/robin850/carrierwave-dropbox` to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Per the documentation that I linked to, those links do expire after four hours: "The /media link expires after four hours, allotting enough time to stream files, but not enough to leave a connection open indefinitely."

Comment: Also, the gem you linked to does call that /media endpoint: https://github.com/robin850/carrierwave-dropbox/blob/fd4bf34915b760dc5d6a8c2f90aeebaf99b420ed/lib/carrierwave/storage/dropbox.rb#L54

Comment: do you know by any chance what to change to make the gem work?

Comment: You could change [`media`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-ruby/api-docs/v1.6.4/DropboxClient.html#method-i-media) to [`shares`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-ruby/api-docs/v1.6.4/DropboxClient.html#method-i-shares) and then [modify the resulting link](https://www.dropbox.com/help/201).

Comment: i have read this in the documentation `shares(path)
Get a URL to share a media file Shareable links created on Dropbox are time-limited, but don't require any authentication, so they can be given out freely. The time limit should allow at least a day of shareability, though users have the ability to disable a link from their account if they like.` does that mean this link expires as well?

Comment: No, by default, these share links created by the /shares API endpoint don't expire by themselves (but they can be revoked manually).

Comment: @Greg I see thanks. I have changed media to shares but which line needs to be modified to change to correct path? seems like a maze to down there.

Comment: @Greg i have managed to get the shared url but its of the form `https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcoc67rxv59apsu/resized_medical_tourism_insurance.jpg?dl=0` and its not recognised as an image any clues?

Comment: That links to a web page with a preview of the image. As I mentioned you'll need to modify it as shown here: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

Comment: thank you for the help greg, i will put the answer here in case somebody needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `carrierwave-dropbox` gem uses the `media` part of the API and greg as pointed in comments this links expires after some hours.

This is the procedure i followed to make it work using `shares`

first find `carrierwave-dropbox gem` install location navigate to

`lib\carrierwave\storage\dropbox.rb`

and change line `54` to the following

`@client.shares(@path, short_url = false)["url"]`

next make a helper method in `application_helper.rb`

```
  def rewrite_url(url)
    u = url
    u.slice! "dl=0"
    u = u + "raw=1"
    u
  end
```

essentially all it does is remove the dl=0 part from the returned string as it directs to preview on dropbox and add `raw=1` at the end to actually show the direct file.

next, call it like this on the image tag

`<%= image_tag rewrite_url(@question.image_url(:resized)) %>`

`:resized` is because i resize the image, the essential part is to wrap the image url into the helper

read_more: [more info](http://dropbox.com/help/201)

Many thanks to **Greg** for the help.